# Drop a file from shell

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to drop a file from windows explorer to my form and I am almost successful :)
After opening explorer window in shell I can drop a file to my form where I have one message box/dialog before accepting.

Problem is in fact that my messagebox with question opens in back of explorer window.
Here is a code:

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.AllowDrop = True
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_DragDrop(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs) Handles Me.DragDrop
    If e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop) Then
        Dim Files() As String
        Files = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop)
        If Files.Length > 0 Then
            Dim ret As Integer = MsgBox("Would you like to upload file?" & vbNewLine & Files(0), MsgBoxStyle.OkCancel + MsgBoxStyle.Question, "Decide please")
            If ret = DialogResult.OK Then
                myModule.UploadF()
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_DragEnter(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs) Handles Me.DragEnter
    If e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop) Then
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.All
    Else
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btn_open_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_open.Click
    Shell("explorer c:\", AppWinStyle.NormalFocus)
End Sub

End Class
```

1) Is here any way to get messagebox to pop in front of explorer window?
2) How to close opened explorer window from my program after usage?

EDIT: Solution for...
1) is to place **Me.Activate** before MsgBox!
2) for that I still don't find a solution.

Comment: There are few file types which behaves different so please note that it is normal for normal people to decide according their wishes/needs! From this point of view "don't use any dialog boxes" is not a close to answer I need!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Add a Dialog to your project. (Found in the list of addable things like form, class etc).
Add a label to it and change the text in the constructor. 
In the Dialogs paint event add this:

```
Me.BringToFront()
```

Then use this dialog instead of MsgBox, it should provide what you need.

It's somewhat of a workaround but it should work.

Edit:

Right, found a better solution.

Add this to the code written in this question before calling MsgBox:

```
Me.BringToFront()
Me.TopMost = True
```

And you will be fine.

Comment: I try this and it behaves a same like builtin msgbox in mean of z-order.

Comment: Thank you WozzeC for trying to help. With help on another forum I already solves this problem (with original message box) by using Me.Activate before msgbox. But you give me an excellent idea. With such dialog I can make my own message box placable anywhere and with more capabilities like "don't show this again", fully localized buttons, etc, etc... :)

Comment: Super duper. Yeah it's easy to forget the possibility of using manually created dialogs.

Answer (score 2):

I know you have already accepted an answer, but i agree with Hans that this implementation is flawed. If the user must click an upload button, then launch an openfiledialog. Opening a plain explorer window that they must drag from is incredibly counter intuitive.

You can keep the drag and drop functionality, but let the user open their own explorer window to use that.

A more intuitive implementation would be to add the dragdrop functionality to a panel, and have a label and a button so the user can choose either method.

Something like this:

[image]

Comment: Well, you should accept that my "upload" scenario is symbolic and that there are users which are unfamiliar with navigating through explorer and those which don't want to lose their time with this kind of work. Additionally, erasing all data from database in order to accept backup file should have at least one question (before erasing). But, your idea which gives choose to user is good!